# Why does Hellboy file down his horns?

Tags: hellboy

In *Hellboy* (2019) the titular part-demon files down his horns nearly flat as part of his daily routine. He even places such a high priority on this that, after assuming his apocalyptic form near the end of the movie, he breaks his horns off immediately.

Why is this? Certainly it doesn't help him blend in, since he has red skin, a tail, and so forth. It can't be hard for him to lift his head given his strength. 
While it's true that Hellboy's horns grow in his apocalyptic form, it doesn't seem like his horns make him evil, rather the other way around.

Comment: The general answer has been that he does it because he feels it makes him a little more human, but I'm having a devil of a time finding a good quote saying as much from the comics or films.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I see what you did there.

Comment: Intentional. Puns are the highest form of humor. :)

Comment: Well this isn't really an answer so I'll make it a comment but... they're giant horns. Aside from probably being kinda heavy, not having them would make it easier to go through doors. I do wonder if, out-of-universe, it might just be easier for Mike Mignola to draw, not having to worry about Red's horns getting in the way.

Comment: Why do we cut our fingernails?

Comment: Humans (and apparently demons) are complex beings and not always 100% rational. Filing down the horns is psychological/symbolic to him.

Comment: Ever tied putting on a sweater with full horns?

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 that gives a whole new meaning to the "fit in" quite from the answer as well...

Comment: 2 anyone with time and scan at the end  of BPRD 1948

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Lol yeah it does, doesn't it? I mean honestly that's probably the best answer. "He does it because it makes life more convenient". I'm pretty sure Hellboy 2 showed him as a kid with filed horns, too. Now, maaaybe Prof. Bruttenholm had an extra motive for filing Red's horns, like if they were connected to his eldritch demon powers, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: "blending in" is not about "blending in so perfectly that nobody can tell you apart from the other guy". It's an asymptotic process, "blending in a bit more".

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'll answer based on the Hellboy comics. I don't know if the first two Hellboy films are regarded as canon, but I have never viewed them as such as they seem to have little connection to the comics. The 2019 film is very close to the comics, though sadly that didn't work out too well.

Anyhow it is a recurring theme in the comics, and especially in the sequel Hellboy in Hell, that Hellboy is destined to rule Hell and deliver all sorts of vaguely defined mayhem. He rejects this destiny, and snapping off his horns is a symbol of that rejection.

The first time we encounter the horn snapping is in Wake the Devil part 5 when Hecate specifically invokes his destiny and sends him down to Hell:

[image: Horns 1]

We see the horns grow as he descends in Hell to take up his destiny:

[image: Horns 2]

And he explicitly rejects that destiny and snaps off the horns as a symbol of that rejection:

[image: Horns 3]

This theme recurs again and again in the comics. I'm not going to post scans of every occasion otherwise this would be a long answer, to say nothing of the copyright issue, but it's the overarching theme of the comics that Hellboy was born of a mortal woman and the archdemon, Azzael, and is destined to rule Hell. This comes to fruition in the final episode of Hellboy in Hell, though I won't say how for fear of spoilers :-)

In the 2019 film Hellboy snaps off his horns to reject Nimue's attempts to persuade him to take up his destiny. This doesn't happen in the comics because the battle with Nimue ends rather differently, but again I won't give spoilers.

So the bottom line is that Hellboy snaps his horns as a symbol of his desire to live a normal life as a mortal among humans. I don't think we ever see Hellboy filing his horns in the comic. Whenever he snaps the horns they leave a smooth surface, and I don't recall any suggestion in the comics that the horns grow naturally like hair or nails do.

Answer (score 43):

This was <strike>lampshaded</strike> addressed in *Hellboy* (2004).

> CLAY: Quit staring.
>
> MYERS: What?
>
> CLAY: His horns. He files them. To fit in.

Comment: How does filing down his horns help him fit in? He's so _red_...not to mention the hand and tail.

Comment: Hence my mention of [lampshading](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging).  Clay's tone of voice there indicates (to me, anyway) that he doesn't believe it either.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand "lampshading", and did not bother to look it up coz it was strikethrough. Does this mean that Clay has one answer, but Hellboy might give a different answer?

Comment: Strikethroughs, when typed, are generally meant to be funny-- as if you wrote the word or phrase you were really thinking, then crossed it out and wrote a more polite one instead.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet: Is this some generally understood notation? Could you give me a reference? As I allways understood and used it in a way, to express, "I dont find this correct anymore, but to better understand further context I still wanted to write it out" Rather than using it for some sort of a joke.

Comment: @Zaibis It's very much a colloquial usage that cropped up on the Internet, originally in discussion forums. I found this [Grammarly article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/strikethrough-formatting-popularity/) which briefly discusses the concept.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet [Here's an article from Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/strikethrough-formatting-popularity/) describing the current usage of strikethrough. Relevant quote: "Today, on the Internet, a strikethrough is a way of saying something without really saying it. For example, a writer might use a strikethrough to indicate her own thoughts on the subject she’s writing about in a quick and annoying funny way."

Comment: I dont know... I find it weird adapting a notation to be "funny" to replace a notation having a practical use, I couldnt have then anymore 

Comment: @Cascabel: It's not a matter of being incognito, but rather of minimizing differences between him and the people he interacts with. Horns are predominantly attached to evil; and it's very realistic that people would be even more intimidated by him if (on top of his red muscly physique) he was sporting two demonic horns. [Who looks more evil here?](http://www.mwctoys.com/images/review_oldhb_7.jpg)

Comment: @Cascabel : How does filing down his horns help him fit in? By signaling that he doesn't embrace them. By signaling that he doesn't want them. By signaling that he's different from others who wear horns and do evil things.

Comment: @Zaibis Ordinarily on the Internet, if you write something, then think better of it, you'd just delete what you typed and correct it.  So intentionally leaving a strikethrough clearly indicates that you want someone to see your initial thought as well as the "correction."  Maybe think of it as the written equivalent of something saying something odd or outrageous and then adding "...just kidding."

Answer (score 5):

John Rennie's answer does an excellent job explaining the symbolic meaning behind Hellboy breaking his horns off in dramatic moments. However, *B.P.R.D. 1948* explains the origin of him mundanely filing them off.

Archie, one of young Hellboy's carers and friends, laughs when Hellboy tries on his hat. Hellboy is going through an emotionally difficult time as his adopted father is away on an extended mission. He locks himself away for over a day. Another of his carers/friends speculates that he's reacting to the difficult conditions of his childhood and discomfort with being "special." He took it extremely personally when, Archie, one of his only friends, laughed at his appearance, at least from his perspective. The story ends with a strong implication that this shame and a desire to be normal is what leads him to start filing his horns.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The question asks why he bothers when he still has other demonic features that he can't change. This origin answers those questions by explaining that

1. He started the routine as child before developing full maturity and critical thinking.
2. He started doing it in reaction to his horns specifically being laughed at.